# How to change how float numbers are displayed in the input in c programs?

Tags: c, input

Let us suppose a very simple program in C that asks some number for the user and do something, like in the following piece of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float var;
    printf("Provide a number:");
    scanf("%f",&var);
    (do something)
    return 0;
}
```

When the user informs, let's say, 12.45, in the scanf, the value 12.45 is displayed. But when the user informs the value 7, I would like that when the user pressed <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, this value would be completed with decimal zeros, like 7.00.

Is there any way to do that using the standard libraries of C?

Comment: You can print the user's input back out with something like `printf("%.2f\n", var)`.  But you are never going to get the user's typed input on the screen to be modified, unless you do a fair amount of work using `ncurses` or the like.

Comment: Jumping around in the terminal/console window to change what the user typed on a previous line is not possible with plain ISO C. However, most [platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform) offer a platform-specific API which provides this functionality. Therefore, if you want to know how to do this on your platform, you will have to specify which platform (i.e. operating system and compiler) you are using.

Comment: Zaratruta, if the input was `"1.0e300\n"`, would you then want a non-exponential output of "1000...hundreds of digits... .00"`?

Comment: If you do need something like this, then by the time you get it working, you will *not* simply be using `scanf`.